# An integral from 0 to infinity

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to show that:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x}{x}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}dx$$
 for any positive integer $n$.
This eqn struck me when I was evaluating $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x}{x}dx $$ and $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}dx$$ for different values of $n$ on Wolfram Alpha, and I noticed that they always came out to be equal.

I verified this eqn to hold from $n=1$ to $n= 26$ on Wolfram Alpha so I generalised it for all positive integer $n$. I tried to prove this using Integration by parts as follows:

\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}dx = \int_0^\infty 1.\frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}dx \\
&= \left[ \frac{sin^{2n}x}{x^2}.x\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\int_0^\infty \frac{2n\sin^{2n-1}x.cosx.x^2-2x.sin^{2n}x}{x^4}.xdx\\
&= 0-2n\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x.cosx}{x}dx + 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}dx \\
&\Rightarrow \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}dx = 2n \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x.cosx}{x}dx\\
\end{align*}
Now I am stuck at the process of proving:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x}{x}dx = 2n\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x.cosx}{x} dx$$
How do I proceed? Please help.

Comment: Please consider the reopening of my question.

Comment: @Henrik,@Hurkyl,@Arnaud D.,@amWhy, please respond and consider my question for reopening votes.

Answer (score 1):

For the evaluation of
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x}{x}dx\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x\cos x}{x}d x,$$
apply the [Power-reduction formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae),
$$\sin^{2n-1}x=\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{2n-1}{n+k}\sin((2k+1)x),$$
note that
$$\sin((2k+1)x)\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin((2k+2)x)+\sin(2kx)\right),$$
and use the fact that for $a>0$,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Hence
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x}{x}dx=
\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{2n-1}{n+k}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin((2k+1)x)}{x}dx=\frac{n\pi}{4^n(2n-1)}\binom{2n}{n}$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n-1}x\cos x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\cdot4^n(2n-1)}\binom{2n}{n}.$$